# Problems reading and writing MIFARE cards

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard, lib-nfc

When I'm triying to read or write a MIFARE Classic card I get the following output:

```
nfc-mfclassic r a mfoc_output.mfd mfoc_output.mfd 
NFC reader: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
Expected MIFARE Classic card with UID starting as: 00000000
Got card with UID starting as:                     049f30b2
Aborting!
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your answer Michael, but that's not working either
This is the output:

```
nfc-mfclassic r a mfoc_output.mfd
NFC reader: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
Found MIFARE Classic card:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
       UID (NFCID1): 04  9f  30  b2  
      SAK (SEL_RES): 08  
Guessing size: seems to be a 1024-byte card
Reading out 64 blocks |nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes: Mifare Authentication Failed
!
failed to read trailer block 0x3f
```

The problem is that I lost the key file and now I can't write or read that tag, i'm triying to generate a key file using mfoc but after dumping keys to a file, nfc-mfclassic still says authentication failed

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> nfc-mfclassic r a mfoc_output.mfd mfoc_output.mfd
> ```

You are using the file `mfoc_output.mfd` both as the destination file for dumping the card contents and as a source file for the key material to access the sectors of the card. Typically this is not what you want as this would overwrite your key file.

> ```
> Expected MIFARE Classic card with UID starting as: 00000000
> Got card with UID starting as:                     049f30b2
> Aborting!
> ```

The problem here is that your key file (specified by the second file name) starts with the bytes `00 00 00 00`. However, `nfc-mfclassic` checks if that file starts with the first 4 bytes of the UID of the MIFARE CLassic tag and will abort the dump procedure if they don't match.

If using the file `mfoc_output.mfd` as both, the destination file and the key file is really what you want, you can either edit the file to start with the first 4 bytes of the tag UID (i.e. with `04 9f 30 b2`), or you can force `nfc-mfclassic` to use the file anyways, by specifying the "force" parameter:

```
 nfc-mfclassic r a mfoc_output.mfd mfoc_output.mfd f
```

If you don't want to use `mfoc_output.mfd` as the key file, you can simply use

```
 nfc-mfclassic r a mfoc_output.mfd
```

instead, which will try to access the MIFARE sectors using some set of default/well-known keys.